# Accessing data through gspread comes up blank for lists

Tags: javascript, python, cs50, gspread

I'm experiencing this odd problem with gspread. I'm using it to access a sheet, and I want to take that data and convey it to the frontend of my website.

I put the data into a variable like so:

```
data = worksheet.get_all_values()
```

And this works, unless I try and access a cell which has what I believe to be a list in it.

[sheets error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyix5.png)

For example, data[2][5] will give "test", but data[3][5] will give nothing (instead of:
"

- Conversation practice
- Advice and mentorship
- Anything!").

The circled cells are the ones which return nothing. Any ideas?